# How to read Mahout clustering output

Tags: mahout

I have run the k-Means clustering algorithm on the synthetic control data from the Mahout tutorial, and was wondering if someone could explain how to interpret the output. I ran clusterdump and received output that looks something like this (truncated to save space):

```
CL-592{n=57 c=30.726, 29.813...] r=[3.528, 3.597...]}
Weight : [props - optional]: Point:
1.0 : [distance=27.453962995925863]: [24.672, 35.261, 30.486...]
1.0 : [distance=27.675053294846002]: [25.592, 29.951, 34.188...]
1.0 : [distance=28.97727289419493]: [30.696, 32.667, 34.223...]
1.0 : [distance=21.999685652862784]: [32.702, 35.219, 30.143...]
...
CL-598{n=50 c=[29.611, 29.769...] r=[3.166, 3.561...]}
Weight : [props - optional]:  Point:
1.0 : [distance=27.266203490250472]: [27.679, 33.506, 23.594...]
1.0 : [distance=28.749781351838173]: [34.727, 28.325, 30.331...]
1.0 : [distance=32.635136046420186]: [27.758, 33.859, 29.879...]
1.0 : [distance=29.328974057024624]: [29.356, 26.793, 25.575...]
```

Could someone explain to me how to read this? From what I understand, CL-__ is a cluster ID, followed by n=number of points in the cluster, c=centroid as a vector, r=radius as a vector, and then each point in the cluster. Is this correct? Furthermore, how do I know which clustered point matches up with which input point? i.e. are the points described as a key-value pair where the key is some kind of ID for the point and the value is the vector? If not is there some way I can set it up so it is?

Comment: Excuse me for bumping in like this, but how did you get clustered points? I can get cluster centroids, but somehow I can't get to relation between points and the clusters that thy have been assigned to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe your interpretation of the data is correct (I've only been working with Mahout for ~3 weeks, so someone more seasoned should probably weigh in on this).

As far as linking points back to the input that created them I've used `NamedVector`, where the name is the key for the vector.  When you read one of the generated points files (`clusteredPoints`) you can convert each row (point vector) back into a `NamedVector` and retrieve the name using `.getName()`.

**Update in response to comment**

When you initially read your data into Mahout, you convert it into a collection of vectors with which you then write to a file (`points`) for use in the clustering algorithms later.  Mahout gives you several `Vector` types which you can use, but they also give you access to a `Vector` wrapper class called `NamedVector` which will allow you to identify each vector.

For example, you could create each `NamedVector` as follows:

```
NamedVector nVec = new NamedVector(
    new SequentialAccessSparseVector(vectorDimensions), 
    vectorName
    );
```

Then you write your collection of `NamedVectors` to file with something like:

```
SequenceFile.Writer writer = new SequenceFile.Writer(...);
VectorWritable writable = new VectorWritable();

// the next two lines will be in a loop, but I'm omitting it for clarity
writable.set(nVec);
writer.append(new Text(nVec.getName()), nVec);
```

You can now use this file as input to one of the clustering algorithms.

After having run one of the clustering algorithms with your points file, it will have generated *yet another* points file, but it will be in a directory named `clusteredPoints`.

You can then read in this points file and extract the name you associated to each vector.  It'll look something like this:

```
IntWritable clusterId = new IntWritable();
WeightedPropertyVectorWritable vector = new WeightedPropertyVectorWritable();

while (reader.next(clusterId, vector))
{
    NamedVector nVec = (NamedVector)vector.getVector();
    // you now have access to the original name using nVec.getName()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @JesseBuesking. I'm a beginner as well so I need some help understanding your response. Where are you defining the points as `NamedVector`? And from where/when can I use `.getName()`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the option -of CSV in clusterdump, you will have a more exploitable result for further treatment.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem,(using mahout 0.6).I am also a beginner. I need to display the documents in the form of clusters to the users. So i will need document names rather that words corresponding to clusters. I have been clustering the text documents from shell script.

Comment: the seqdumper can be used to get the mapping of the cluster and the files.

Comment: if u want the output to contain file names rather than vectors, use Named Vectors attribute.