# Mahout clustering: Error in retrieving the name of a named vector using seqdumper

Tags: k-means, mahout

I am using mahout for k-means clustering on a directory containing 12 documents with the help of following commands:

```
mahout seq2sparse -i /user/manisha1414/dir_001-seqfiles -o /user/manisha1414/dir_001-vectors --maxDFPercent 85 --namedVector
mahout seqdumper -i /user/manisha1414/dir_001-kmeans-clusters/clusteredPoints/part-m-00000 > ./dir_001-cluster-docs.txt
```

I am getting the following Output

```
Key: 0: Value: wt: 1.0 distance: 47.44299700930014  vec: [{"0":2.386},{"2":1.875},{"9":2.386},{"14":2.386......... 
Key: 11: Value: wt: 1.0 distance: 217.4603558919857  vec: [{"0":2.386},{"2":1.875},{".........
```

I am not getting vector-ids in above output.

Please help me to get vector-ids also in the output !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  "--namedVector true" while converting your sequencefiles to vector.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried this, seqdumper didn't include the named vectors. In addition to setting --namedVector, the workaround is to use clusterdump. The output format needs to be set using '-of CSV' because the default text output format doesn't save named vectors either.

```
mahout clusterdump -d /user/manisha1414/docs-vectors/dictionary.file-0 -i /user/manisha1414/dir_001-kmeans-clusters/clusters-3-final -o clusters.csv -p /user/manisha1414/dir_001-kmeans-clusters/clusteredPoints -dt sequencefile -b 100 -n 20 -of CSV --evaluate
```

Mohammad points this out in [How to read Mahout clustering output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848038/how-to-read-mahout-clustering-output)